# csv.writer not writing entire list to file that it was read from

Tags: python, list, csv

When reading a CSV into a list and then trying to write back directly to that same CSV with some modifications I am finding that the script skips to the next file prematurely at the **exact** same point every time.

Changing the outputfile to a secondary file (.e. `filea.csv` is read and the write is `fileaCorrected.csv`) works.

```py
import time
import datetime
import csv
import sys
import glob
import pdb

pattern1 = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'
pattern2 = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
pattern3 = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

folderLocation = input("which Folder should be scanned and trimmed EX C:\program files\data:")
endDate = input("what is the last timestamp that should be in the file(s): ")

trimDate = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(endDate, pattern1)))

fileList = sorted(glob.glob(folderLocation+'/*.csv'))

for FileName in fileList:

    removedLines = 0
    FilesComplete = 0
    f = open(FileName)
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    #pdb.set_trace()
    header = next(f)
    newFileName = (FileName[:-4]) + " endateremoved.csv"
    with open(FileName, 'w') as csvfile:
        filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        csvfile.write(header)
        for row in csv_f:
            #(FileName," -- ",row[0])
            date_time = row[0]
            epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date_time, pattern3)))
            if epoch < trimDate:
                lineWriter = ""
                for item in row[:-1]:
                    lineWriter += item + ","
                lineWriter += row[-1]
                #print(lineWriter)
                csvfile.write(lineWriter + "\n")
            else:
                #print("removed line %s" % row)
                removedLines += 1
                break
    FilesComplete += 1
    print (str(FilesComplete) + " Files Completed")
    print("%d files had removed lines" % removedLines)'
```

I feel as though I am making a minor mistake in the script that is causing the file to end prematurely.

example 
input

```
car,a
boat,b
plane,c
```

output

```
car,a
boat,b
pla
```

I could create a workaround that delete the old files and rename the new ones but that seems janky? Any thoughts on this are appreciated.

Comment: in `for`-loop you use `break` which exits this loop - so it may skips some lines.

Comment: You should write to `filewriter` not `csvfile` but not sure why you are bothering with csv because basically you are copying input file to output files.

Comment: instead of creating string which you write using `csvfile.write()` you could add item to `row` and use `filewriter.writerow(row)`

Comment: No `csvfile` is just a file handle, which writes strings. Filewriter is the csv interface. That’s the problem, I think; you are using csv ut there is no real csv processing involved, and you are writing to file something that is just a string

Comment: you shouldn't write to file which you read - you can overwrite data before you read them. Better write to new file and rename it after you will have all in file.

Comment: @barny
Correct - I am copying an input file and cutting the file short based on the timestamp input. Basically on any given file I need data up until a specific time frame, and nothing past it.

Comment: furas I could be wrong but using PDB I see that my list shows the entire csv using for x in csv_f: print(x). Am I not correct in assuming that the csv_f doesn't hold the entire csv in it's list?  I realize that I could write to another file, but that introduces more problems that I would have to solve.